# a problem on test of converges of two series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Test the following series for convergence:
>
> (a)$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+5/4}}$$
>
> (b)$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\tan \left(\frac{1}{n} \right)}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Which formula/test would be useful to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

Useful formulas/results here:

- $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n=e$;
- $\tan\left(\frac  1n\right)\overset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}\frac 1n$;
- $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac 1{n^{\alpha}}$ is convergent if and only if $\alpha>1$;
- If $0<u_n, v_n$, $u_n=(1+\varepsilon_n)v_n$, where $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\varepsilon_n=0$, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}u_n$ is convergent if and only if so is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}v_n$.

Comment: +1 for indicating useful tools rather than writing down a full proof.

Comment: @did See the Kummer test in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KummersTest.html

Comment: @Elias Listen, I am flattered by the attention, but why do you see fit to provide me with a reference to Kummer's test?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: [Raabe's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test), a higher order ratio test, works nicely for both of these series.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Kummer's Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KummersTest.html):

> Given a series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}u_i$ of positive terms $u_i$ and a sequence of finite positive constants $a_i$, let
>   $$
> \rho=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_n\cdot\frac{ u_n}{u_{n+1}}-a_{n+1}\right).
> $$
>
> 1. If $\rho>0$, the series converges.
> 2. If $\rho<0$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/a_n$ diverges, the series diverges.
> 3. If $\rho=0$, the series may converge or diverge.

The test is a general case of Bertrand's test, the root test, Gauss's test, and Raabe's test. With $a_n=n$ and $a_{(n+1)}=n+1$, the test becomes Raabe's test.